# EF6 stored procedure must declare scalar variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am trying to call a stored procedure using C# EF6 to bring back data.  I have tried to run the stored procedure in SQL management studio and it seems to work fine, however when I try to run it in my application I get an error saying `"Must declare the scalar variable "@devID"`

Here is part of my method in my application calling the stored procedure

```
 public IHttpActionResult GetMetrics(int deviceID, string attribute, string startDate)
    {

        if (deviceID == 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var metrics = db.Database.SqlQuery<Metrics>("GetMetrics @devID, @MetricType, @startTime", deviceID, attribute, startDate).ToList();
```

and here is my stored procedure:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetMetrics]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @devID int,
    @MetricType nvarchar(20),
    @startTime nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    SELECT * 
    FROM dbMetrics
    WHERE deviceID = @devID and MetricType = @MetricType and timeStamp >= @startTime
    ORDER BY timeStamp 
END
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx), if you want to use named parameters, you need to pass `SqlParameter` objects like this:

```
var metrics = db.Database.SqlQuery<Metrics>("GetMetrics @devID, @MetricType, @startTime", 
    new SqlParameter("devID", deviceID),
    new SqlParameter("MetricType", attribute),
    new SqlParameter("startTime", startDate)
).ToList();
```